Can't startup expo project from terminal on my Mac
Command prompt npx create expo-app
returns this error:
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/baguma/.npm/_logs/2024-07-20T21_08_19_791Z-debug-0.log


I have uninstalled node modules folder and packages-lock.json. No work done
